# Does ML.Net allow to train multi-input models?

Tags: image-processing, model, ml.net, ml.net-model-builder

My requirement is to Use images and text inputs together to train a model.

Currently I use Image classification model to predict using a given Image.

But I wish to use some text inputs too to train the model.

Is there any way to do it using ML.net ?